# Swift macOS wallpaper set fit style

Tags: swift

I managed to set the wallpaper for macOS by:

```
let workspace = NSWorkspace.shared
 if let screen = NSScreen.main  {
     try workspace.setDesktopImageURL(imgurl, for: screen, options: [:])
     //imgurl is the url location of the required image
     }
 } catch {
     print(error)
 }
```

However, how do I set the fit style (like fill screen, fit to screen, etc)? Will it be in options?

Comment: See the doc for setDesktopImageURL(_:for:options:).

Comment: @ElTomato I am trying to scale it. So far I have try workspace.setDesktopImageURL(imgurl, for: screen, options: [NSWorkspace.DesktopImageOptionKey.imageScaling : ]). But I am confused about the value of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved it :

```
try workspace.setDesktopImageURL(imgurl, for: screen, options: [NSWorkspace.DesktopImageOptionKey.imageScaling : 5])
//The value of the dictionary is the desired number you want to scale the image by.
```

Comment: love how the type of `.imageScaling` isn't documented ;)

Comment: It is: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/desktopimageoptionkey/1534270-imagescaling